# Microsoft Access Query Input Criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am making a query for my database which contains a customer information table and payment table. I need to track monthly payments and contact those who have not paid by the end of each month. I am working on a query to output a list of all who have not paid during the month. People are able to pay for one month at a time or multiple months. I have a string field in my payment table where I record which month was paid for. The value could be, for example, "June" or "June, July, August" For my query I want to be able to input a given month and be able to see who has not paid.

I have made an input for the query where I can type in any month, and it will return payments for other months or when someone has not paid at all, but I am not able to return those whose values don't exactly match my input of "June" or any other single month. I am using the like function here. Here is my code:

```
SELECT Clients.[Player ID], Clients.[Player Name], Clients.[Contact Number], Payment.[Payment Amount], Payment.[Payment Month]
FROM Clients INNER JOIN Payment ON Clients.[Player ID] = Payment. [Player ID]
WHERE (((Payment.[Payment Month]) Not Like [Enter the month:])) OR (((Payment.[Payment Month]) Is Null));
```

When I run the query for an input of "June", it returns people who have done "June, July, August" as unpaid for the month of May. I know this is because "May, June, July" is different from the input value of "May." Is there a way that I can exclude these payments from the list of unpaid? I don't want the query to return any values that may include the input month. I was thinking that I may need to use a wildcard but I was unsure of how exactly to put this criteria in the query, or if I need to write any additional SQL code for it.

Comment: You should _normalise_ your database, having a record for each paid year-month per customer. That would make your task a snap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this really is a string and not a multi-value field and normalizing is not an option at this time, try:

```
SELECT Clients.[Player ID], Clients.[Player Name], Clients.[Contact Number], Payment.[Payment Amount], Payment.[Payment Month]
FROM Clients INNER JOIN Payment ON Clients.[Player ID] = Payment. [Player ID]
WHERE (((Payment.[Payment Month]) Not Like "*" & [Enter the month:] & "*")) OR (((Payment.[Payment Month]) Is Null));
```

Advise not to use popup input parameters because cannot validate user input. Have user input value into control such as combobox on form and reference that control as parameter.